# How to refresh fragment onTabReselected?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Here's my code.

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
  @Override
  public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
  }

  @Override
  public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    Toast.makeText(getContext, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // toast is not working.
  }
});

return view;
```

I want to refresh the fragment because I used API and I need to re-fetched the data everytime the tab is selected.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
                Fragment1 fragment1 = (Fragment1) adapter.instantiateItem(viewPager, 0);
                if (fragment1 != null) {
                    fragment1.fragmentBecameVisible();
                }
            }else if(viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 1) {
                Fragment2 fragment2 = (Fragment2) adapter.instantiateItem(viewPager, 1);

                if (fragment2 != null) {
                    fragment2.fragmentBecameVisible();
                }
            }
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
```

Add this two interface

```
public interface Fragment1 {
    void fragmentBecameVisible();
}

public interface Fragment2 {
    void fragmentBecameVisible();
}
```

and then implement fragment from that interface and use methos in your fragament

```
@Override
public void fragmentBecameVisible() {
    //do your task heree
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this tutorial. If any issue you can ask there. http://blog.tamanneupane.com/fragment-refresh/

Answer (score 0):

You can update the onResume() of your fragment to somewhat mentioned below or set         viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0/1); //I think its 0 but u can try & look what works for you!

```
@Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();

            if(somecondition) {
               call code executing API functionality
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

override this method and call the method here.

```
 @Override
        public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
            super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

          if(isVisibleToUser){

                 // this will call when the fragment is visible to the user.
                 // call your API or fetch_data() here.           

                   }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pull to refresh method if your base APIs are 18+
You can refer here https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Implementing-Pull-to-Refresh-Guide it shows how to refresh fragments using pull to refresh. Been using it quite in my app. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Set given code after set viewpager in tablayout :

TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(current_tab);

tab.select();